# React Native: how to set different state values from multiple identical child components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-component

I'm rendering two sliders on a screen, one for maximum distance, and one for an age range (which has two draggable icons). What I want to do is set those corresponding values in my Redux store based on which component is being used at that point. For example, if the user slides the age range slider, it should set the ageLow and ageHigh values in the store, but if the distance slider is changed, the maxDistance value is set.

I could set maxDistance or the age range based on whether rangeEnabled is true or false inside the Child, but this seems very inflexible if I wanted to later add another slider somewhere.

What is the best way to achieve my goal here?

**The parent component:**

```
const Settings = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.sliderView}>
            <LabeledSlider label="Maximum Distance" min={1} max={100} />
            <Space height={5} />
            <LabeledSlider label="Age Range" rangeEnabled={true} min={18} max={100} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**The child component:**

```
import RangeSlider from 'rn-range-slider'

const LabeledSlider = memo(({ label, rangeEnabled=false, min, max }) => {

  return (
    <View> 
        <View>
            // ... label
        </View>
        <RangeSlider
            style={{width: 350, height: 80}}
            rangeEnabled={rangeEnabled}
            gravity={'center'}
            min={min}
            max={max}
            step={1}
            labelStyle='none'
            selectionColor={SAFFRON}
            blankColor={INDIAGREEN}
            onValueChanged={(low, high) => {...something}/>   
    </View>
  )
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Settings = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleChange = (type, low, high) => {
    // do stuff
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.sliderView}>
      <LabeledSlider onChange={handleChange} type="type1" label="Maximum Distance"    min={1} max={100} />
      <Space height={5} />
      <LabeledSlider onChange={handleChange} type="type2" label="Age Range" rangeEnabled min={18} max={100} />
    </View>
  );
};

const LabeledSlider = memo(({ onChange, type, label, rangeEnabled = false, min, max }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View />
      <RangeSlider
        style={{ width: 350, height: 80 }}
        rangeEnabled={rangeEnabled}
        gravity="center"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        step={1}
        labelStyle="none"
        selectionColor={SAFFRON}
        blankColor={INDIAGREEN}
        onValueChanged={(low, high) => {
          onChange(type, low, high);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
});
```